# Afterlogic mail client installation error

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, nginx, email-client

I am trying to manually install the `Afterlogic` mail client on `Ubuntu 20.04 (x86_64)`. I have downloaded zip from https://afterlogic.org/webmail-lite. `Afterlogic` is located here: `/var/lib/afterlogic`

I use the `Hestia` control panel. The problem is when I run http://XX.XXX.XX.XX/afterlogic/adminpanel to configure it, then I got the following error:

> Page Not Found Oops! We couldn’t find the page that you’re looking
> for. Please check the address and try again. Error Code: 404

**Web Server:**

```
Proxy Server: nginx 
Web Server: apache2 
Backend Server: php-fpm
```

I think, the webserver does not detect `Afterlogic` path. So, I need to provide it.
I have created the `afterlogic.conf` file and put it here: `/etc/apache2/sites-available`.

**afterlogic.conf** file content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName MY_WEBSERVER_IP;
DocumentRoot /var/lib/afterlogic;
ServerAdmin admin@domain.com;

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/afterlogic-error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/afterlogic-access.log combined

<Directory /var/lib/afterlogic>
      Options -Indexes
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have restarted the server, cleared the browser cache but it still displays 404 error. Any ideas how to fix it? Thanks.

Also, I have run these commands to install it via installer: https://afterlogic.com/docs/webmail-lite/installation/installing-on-debian-ubuntu-linux

**The output from installation:**

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-107-generic x86_64)

* Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com
* Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
* Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage
Last login: Tue Apr 5 12:34:49 2022 from XXX.XXX.XX.XXX
root@my-server:~# wget -qO - http://apt.afterlogic.com/afterlogic.asc | apt-key add -
OK
root@my-server:~# apt install gnupg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
gnupg is already the newest version (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
debugedit geoip-database libarchive13 libdw1 libgeoip1 liblua5.2-0 libnspr4 libnss3 librpm8 librpmbuild8 librpmio8
librpmsign8 rpm-common rpm2cpio
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 25 not upgraded.
root@my-server:~# apt update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/apache2/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:4 http://mirror.fra10.de.leaseweb.net/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:5 http://mirror.fra10.de.leaseweb.net/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:6 https://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:7 https://apt.hestiacp.com focal InRelease
Get:8 http://mirror.fra10.de.leaseweb.net/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Get:9 http://apt.afterlogic.com/stable InRelease [1,086 B]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main i386 Packages [415 kB]
Get:11 https://dlm.mariadb.com/repo/mariadb-server/10.6/repo/ubuntu focal InRelease [7,767 B]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [1,381 kB]
Get:13 http://mirror.fra10.de.leaseweb.net/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,708 kB]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [239 kB]
Get:15 http://mirror.fra10.de.leaseweb.net/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [627 kB]
Get:16 http://mirror.fra10.de.leaseweb.net/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages [676 kB]
Get:17 http://mirror.fra10.de.leaseweb.net/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [915 kB]
Get:18 http://apt.afterlogic.com/stable Packages [5,733 B]
Fetched 6,312 kB in 1s (4,267 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
25 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
root@my-server:~# apt install afterlogic-lite
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
debugedit geoip-database libarchive13 libdw1 libgeoip1 liblua5.2-0 libnspr4 libnss3 librpm8 librpmbuild8 librpmio8
librpmsign8 rpm-common rpm2cpio
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
libapache2-mod-php libapache2-mod-php8.1 php8.1-bcmath php8.1-bz2 php8.1-cli php8.1-common php8.1-curl php8.1-dev
php8.1-fpm php8.1-gd php8.1-imap php8.1-intl php8.1-ldap php8.1-mbstring php8.1-mysql php8.1-opcache php8.1-pspell
php8.1-readline php8.1-soap php8.1-xml php8.1-zip
Suggested packages:
dh-php
The following NEW packages will be installed:
afterlogic-lite libapache2-mod-php libapache2-mod-php8.1
The following packages will be upgraded:
php8.1-bcmath php8.1-bz2 php8.1-cli php8.1-common php8.1-curl php8.1-dev php8.1-fpm php8.1-gd php8.1-imap
php8.1-intl php8.1-ldap php8.1-mbstring php8.1-mysql php8.1-opcache php8.1-pspell php8.1-readline php8.1-soap
php8.1-xml php8.1-zip
19 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 26.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 99.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.1-bcmath amd64 8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [15.5 kB]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.1-zip amd64 8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [24.2 kB]
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.1-xml amd64 8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [106 kB]
Get:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.1-soap amd64 8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [121 kB]
Get:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.1-readline amd64 8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [12.8 kB]
Get:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.1-pspell amd64 8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [8,924 B]
Get:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.1-opcache amd64 8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [333 kB]
Get:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.1-mysql amd64 8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [116 kB]
Get:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.1-mbstring amd64 8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [392 kB]
Get:10 http://apt.afterlogic.com/stable afterlogic-lite 9.3.2.build6 [18.4 MB]
Get:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.1-ldap amd64 8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [30.8 kB]
Get:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.1-intl amd64 8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [126 kB]
Get:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.1-imap amd64 8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [31.6 kB]
Get:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.1-gd amd64 8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [28.7 kB]
Get:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.1-fpm amd64 8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [1,673 kB]
Get:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.1-dev amd64 8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [487 kB]
Get:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.1-curl amd64 8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [33.7 kB]
Get:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.1-bz2 amd64 8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [10.7 kB]
Get:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.1-cli amd64 8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [1,659 kB]
Get:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 php8.1-common amd64 8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [1,092 kB]
Get:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libapache2-mod-php8.1 amd64 8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [1,598 kB]
Get:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libapache2-mod-php all 2:8.1+92+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+2 [7,464 B]
Fetched 26.3 MB in 4s (7,426 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 91243 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-php8.1-bcmath_8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php8.1-bcmath (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) over (8.1.3-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../01-php8.1-zip_8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php8.1-zip (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) over (8.1.3-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../02-php8.1-xml_8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php8.1-xml (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) over (8.1.3-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../03-php8.1-soap_8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php8.1-soap (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) over (8.1.3-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../04-php8.1-readline_8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php8.1-readline (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) over (8.1.3-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../05-php8.1-pspell_8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php8.1-pspell (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) over (8.1.3-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../06-php8.1-opcache_8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php8.1-opcache (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) over (8.1.3-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../07-php8.1-mysql_8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php8.1-mysql (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) over (8.1.3-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../08-php8.1-mbstring_8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php8.1-mbstring (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) over (8.1.3-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../09-php8.1-ldap_8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php8.1-ldap (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) over (8.1.3-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../10-php8.1-intl_8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php8.1-intl (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) over (8.1.3-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../11-php8.1-imap_8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php8.1-imap (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) over (8.1.3-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../12-php8.1-gd_8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php8.1-gd (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) over (8.1.3-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../13-php8.1-fpm_8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php8.1-fpm (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) over (8.1.3-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../14-php8.1-dev_8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php8.1-dev (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) over (8.1.3-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../15-php8.1-curl_8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php8.1-curl (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) over (8.1.3-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../16-php8.1-bz2_8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php8.1-bz2 (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) over (8.1.3-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../17-php8.1-cli_8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php8.1-cli (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) over (8.1.3-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../18-php8.1-common_8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php8.1-common (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) over (8.1.3-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libapache2-mod-php8.1......................................................]
Preparing to unpack .../19-libapache2-mod-php8.1_8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libapache2-mod-php8.1 (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ............................................]
Selecting previously unselected package libapache2-mod-php.##......................................................]
Preparing to unpack .../20-libapache2-mod-php_2%3a8.1+92+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libapache2-mod-php (2:8.1+92+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) ..............................................]
Selecting previously unselected package afterlogic-lite.#######....................................................]
Preparing to unpack .../21-afterlogic-lite_9.3.2.build6_all.deb ...
Unpacking afterlogic-lite (9.3.2.build6) ...####################...................................................]
Setting up php8.1-common (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...................................................]
Setting up php8.1-imap (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...###...............................................]
Setting up php8.1-gd (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...#######.............................................]
Setting up php8.1-curl (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...#######...........................................]
Setting up php8.1-xml (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...##########.........................................]
Setting up php8.1-soap (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...###########.......................................]
Setting up php8.1-mysql (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...#############....................................]
Setting up php8.1-zip (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...#################..................................]
Setting up php8.1-pspell (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...################................................]
Setting up php8.1-readline (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...################..............................]
Setting up php8.1-opcache (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...###################............................]
Setting up php8.1-intl (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...########################..........................]
Setting up php8.1-ldap (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...###########################.......................]
Setting up php8.1-bcmath (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...###########################.....................]
Setting up php8.1-bz2 (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...################################...................]
Setting up php8.1-mbstring (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...#############################.................]
Setting up php8.1-cli (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...####################################...............]
Setting up php8.1-dev (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...#######################################............]
Setting up libapache2-mod-php8.1 (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Progress: [ 89%] [######################################################################################...........]
Creating config file /etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini with new version
Module mpm_event disabled.
Enabling module mpm_prefork.
apache2_switch_mpm Switch to prefork
apache2_invoke: Enable module php8.1
Setting up afterlogic-lite (9.3.2.build6) ...############################################################..........]
PHP Warning: Module 'geoip' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Installation is completed successfully.
Log into WebMail admin interface at:
http://localhost/afterlogic/adminpanel/
using login superadmin with empty password to configure product.
Users will be able to log into WebMail at:
http://localhost/afterlogic/
Setting up php8.1-fpm (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
NOTICE: Not enabling PHP 8.1 FPM by default.##############################################################.........]
NOTICE: To enable PHP 8.1 FPM in Apache2 do:
NOTICE: a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
NOTICE: a2enconf php8.1-fpm
NOTICE: You are seeing this message because you have apache2 package installed.
Setting up libapache2-mod-php (2:8.1+92+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) ...##################################........]
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.15) ...
Processing triggers for php8.1-cli (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Processing triggers for libapache2-mod-php8.1 (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...#####################......]
Processing triggers for php8.1-fpm (8.1.4-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...##################################....]
NOTICE: Not enabling PHP 8.1 FPM by default.####################################################################...]
NOTICE: To enable PHP 8.1 FPM in Apache2 do:
NOTICE: a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
NOTICE: a2enconf php8.1-fpm
NOTICE: You are seeing this message because you have apache2 package installed.
root@my-server:~# reboot
Connection to XX.XXX.XX.XX closed by remote host.
Connection to XX.XXX.XX.XX closed.

C:\Windows\system32>ssh -R 8080:localhost:80 root@XX.XXX.XX.XX
root@XX.XXX.XX.XX's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-107-generic x86_64)

* Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com
* Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
* Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage
Last login: Tue Apr 5 14:03:36 2022 from XXX.XXX.XX.XXX
root@my-server:~find / -name afterlogic
/etc/afterlogic
/usr/share/doc/afterlogic
/usr/share/afterlogic
/usr/share/afterlogic/vendor/afterlogic
root@my-server:~#
```

But it still display the 404 error.

**Screenshot:**
[error 404 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2CeG.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this Afterlogic issue.

**Solution:**

1. Create the `afterlogic` directory here: `/var/www/html/`, so the path will be: `/var/www/html/afterlogic`;
2. Navigate to this directory and unzip the content of the `afterlogic` archive to this directory: `unzip afterlogic.zip`;
3. Open the browser and navigate to: http://XX.XXX.XX.XX/afterlogic/, you will get 500 error.
4. Navigate to `/var/www/html/afterlogic` and remove the `.htaccess` file. This file is not required, since the `/data` directory is protected by another `.htaccess` file which will lead to `500` error, if someone tries to access it over Internet.
5. You will get to the login page: `http://XX.XXX.XX.XX/afterlogic/`, but you will be unable to configure it since there is another error: **system not configured**. So to fix it, please run the following command: `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/afterlogic`. This command will set the appropriate permissions.
6. Now, you can configure the `Afterlogic` mail client and everything should work just fine.

The issue is resolved. Thank you.